# Count the number of strings that with k fixes can be turned to a valid parentheses expression

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

Given a number n, we can count all the valid parentheses expressions of lengths 2n and their number is equal to C(n) - Catalan number n. How can I count the number of strings that are almost k valid as function of k and n? for example the string     "((()" is almost 1 valid since we can change 1 parenthesis and obtain "(())" or "()()" and the string "((((" is almost 2 valid since we need to change at least 2 parenthesis and obtain "(())" or "()()". k denotes the number of minimal changes that should be done to get a valid string.

Comment: Well this means each "almost valid" string is obtained by being one change away from a valid string. Note that no two valid strings are 1 change away.

Comment: Almost 1 valid string is one change away from a valid string, but I am trying to get an expression that is function of both k and n, where k is the minimal number of changes and 2n is the length of the string. For example "((((" is almost 2 valid since the minimal number of changes is 2 in order to get "(())" or "()()"

Comment: Would this [less precise estimate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3999257/177399) be of use to you?

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to get a formula and not just an estimate.